# How do I write the results of a deep nested JSON comparison in a new JSON file, which contains additions, deletions, and replacements?

Tags: java, json

I have the following code, which outputs the changes between my source JSON file, and my target JSON file. However, I'm shaky on how to build up, and append to my new JSON, which will be essentially the same as the source JSON, but with the additions, deletions, and replacements from the target JSON.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;



public class CompareJSON {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String jsonSource = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("jsonsource.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        String jsonTarget = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("jsontarget.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        CompareJSON.compareJson(JsonParser.parseString(jsonSource), JsonParser.parseString(jsonTarget), "");
    }

    public static JSONObject toJsonObj(String fileName) {
        File f = new File(fileName);
        try {
            if (f.exists()) {
                InputStream is = new FileInputStream(fileName);
                String jsonTxt = IOUtils.toString(is, "UTF-8");
                System.out.println(jsonTxt);
                return new JSONObject(jsonTxt);
            }
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static void compareJson(JsonElement json, JsonElement other, String path) {
        if (json.equals(other)) {
            return;
        }

        if (json.isJsonArray() && other.isJsonArray()) {
            JsonArray arrJ = (JsonArray) json;
            JsonArray arrO = (JsonArray) other;

            int size = Math.min(arrJ.size(), arrO.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                compareJson(arrJ.get(i), arrO.get(i), path + "/" + i);
            }
            if (arrJ.size() > arrO.size()) {
                for (int i = arrO.size(); i < arrJ.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(path + "/ deleted array value: " + arrJ.get(i));
                }
            } else if (arrJ.size() < arrO.size()) {
                for (int i = arrJ.size(); i < arrO.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(path + "/ added array value: " + arrO.get(i));
                }
            }
        } else if (json.isJsonObject() && other.isJsonObject()) {
            JsonObject objJ = (JsonObject) json;
            JsonObject objO = (JsonObject) other;

            for (Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : objJ.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                JsonElement value = entry.getValue();
                if (objO.has(key)) {
                    compareJson(value, objO.get(key), path + "/" + key);
                } else {
                    System.out.println(path + "/ deleted object entry: \"" + key + "\": " + value);
                }
            }
            for (Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : objO.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                JsonElement value = entry.getValue();
                if (!objJ.has(key)) {
                    System.out.println(path + "/ added object entry: \"" + key + "\": " + value);
                }
            }
        } else if (json.isJsonPrimitive() && other.isJsonPrimitive()) {
            System.out.println(path + "/ value changed: " + json + " -> " + other);
        } else {
            System.out.println(path + "/ element changed: " + json + " -> " + other);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have two JSON objects, obj1 and obj2, you could do something like this:

```java
JSONObject result = new JSONObject(obj1);
for (String key : obj2.keySet()) {
    if (obj1.has(key)) {
        // handle value change
    } else {
        // handle addition
    }
}
for (String key : obj1.keySet()) {
    if (!obj2.has(key)) {
        // handle deletion
    }
}
```